# Get the all coordinates (points ) inside a polygon boundery

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2

I work on the following map in arcgis10.2 and i get vertices in bounderies [image]

I need to get all coordinates (points )inside this polygon(map).How can i get it ?

Comment: You want every single XY coordinate that is within that polygon boundary?

Comment: yes .i get the vertices but know i need to get points inside it.

Comment: Why would you need to know every XY coordinate? Can't you instead just test whether or not an individual point is inside the boundary?

Comment: i need these points to plot a heat map only for this polygon

Comment: Theoretically there are an infinite number of points within this (or any) polygon. Do you need this as a regular grid of points (cells) within this polygon? Do you need to extract a sample of existing points?

Comment: yes as a regular grid of points  ..i need to extract a sample of points which be enough to plot my heat maps ..

Answer (score 5):

Polygon to raster will create a raster with the correct sampling distance which you then convert to points over the extent giving you a regular spaced grid of points for the polygon plus some, select the polygon and use clip or other method to extract the points... done!

Comment: Please can explain me more .I still new to arcgis program

Comment: If you're using ArcGis 10 find the search and search for these tools by name. They are in the toolbox, but so are a great many others so browsing to them is frustrating. The geoprocessing tools you will need are 'polygon to raster', 'raster to point' and 'clip (analasys)'. Launch the tools and drag and drop the inputs from catalog or map and fill in the blanks.

Answer (score 1):

Getting all points to reuse it in drowning  a heat map make your problem take along time for processing . I suggest you to construct several polygons from this polygon and then get the vertices of these polygons (this give you a net of vertices can help you to drow the heat maps ).this may be  asimple easy solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar use case and first attempted to do a hit test for every coordinate in a bounding box - many millions of coordinates. As expected the performance was terrible so I looked for an alternate method.

I found the best performance for my use case was to create an image with a filled polygon - scaled to whatever accuracy I needed, then checked the a pixel color to determine the if the coordinate was inside the polygon.

I was also rendering these results in a heatmap with a blur of 10px so I was able to scale an image of the Philippines to 192 x 108 pixels (10% of the output size) to test only 20,736 coordinates in 0.002 seconds.